# pandas equivalent to .rda/.rdata

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large data frame of around 1000 columns. After doing all the missing value treatment and changing the data types to what I want, I have been able to reduce the size of this data frame to almost half. I did this by changing a lot of int64 to int16 and object to category.

After doing similar operations in R, I can save this new data frame to .rda format and just load it back. This helps me directly get all the variables in the format that I had after doing all the manipulation. Is there a way that I can save it in python and then reload this particular data format so that the data types are maintained?

P.S. - Writing to a csv and loading it back makes me do some work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, 3], B=list('XYZ')))
df.A = df.A.astype(np.int16)
df.B = pd.Categorical(df.B)

df

   A  B
0  1  X
1  2  Y
2  3  Z
```

---

```
df.dtypes

A       int16
B    category
dtype: object
```

---

### You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html)

Save to `hdf`
Use `format='table'` because NotImplementedError from categorical

```
df.to_hdf('small.h5', 'this_df', format='table')
```

Read back in

```
df1 = pd.read_hdf('small.h5', 'this_df')

df1

   A  B
0  1  X
1  2  Y
2  3  Z
```

Check `dtypes`

```
df.dtypes

A       int16
B    category
dtype: object
```

Check equvivalence

```
df1.equals(df)

True
```

---

### Use `feather`

You might need to install the feather-format

```
conda install feather-format -c conda-forge
```

Or

```
pip install -U feather-format
```

Then

```
df.to_feather('small.feather')

df1 = pd.read_feather('small.feather')

df1.equals(df)

True
```

The advantages of `feather` are that you should also be able to read them in **R** and reading and writing should be very fast.

---

### Crude time comparison

```
%timeit pd.read_feather('small.feather')
%timeit pd.read_hdf('small.h5', 'this_df')

842 µs ± 11.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
23.2 ms ± 479 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into the pickle module, should be all you need:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html